# Retrieve multiple values with $jinput

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

How can I retrieve resource_id from the url below?

```
index.php?option=com_ajax&module=booking_form&method=getBooking&format=json&Itemid=131&date=2016-02-04T00:00:00.000Z&end=1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z&resource_id=43&resource_id=45&room=41&start=1970-01-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

I've tried using the following code snippet

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input
$multiple_res = $jinput->getVar('resource_id',array(),'', 'ARRAY');
```

Comment: why are you passing 2 times resource id in your URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your URL to:

```
index.php?option=com_ajax&module=booking_form&method=getBooking&format=json&Itemid=131&date=2016-02-04T00:00:00.000Z&end=1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z&resource_id[]=43&resource_id[]=45&room=41&start=1970-01-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

Otherwise it will only get last `resource_id` value (`45`).

And get array of both values

```
$resource = $jinput->get('resource_id', array(), 'ARRAY');
```

results in

```
Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => 45 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `get`, rather than `getVar`.

Also, `resource_id` appears to be an integer, not an array.

You can use the following:

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$resource = $jinput->get('resource_id', '', 'INT');
```

or:

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$resource = $jinput->getInt('resource_id', '');
```